# Rabbit MQ with javascript

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I would like to use rabbitMQ with javascript. I found some examples using node.js. However none using javascript without node.js.

Can someone give any pointers? My website server if flask based, and the front-end is html/javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage STOMP interoperability feature to achieve what you want.

Introduction about Stomp from the [official site](https://stomp.github.io/):

> STOMP is a simple text-orientated messaging protocol. It defines an
>   interoperable wire format so that any of the available STOMP clients
>   can communicate with any STOMP message broker to provide easy and
>   widespread messaging interoperability among languages and platforms
>   (the STOMP web site has a list of STOMP client and server
>   implementations.

You [can use STOMP over websockets](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/), a technology supported by [most](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) modern browsers.

Finally to integrate RabbitMQ with STOMP you can use the [RabbitMQ STOMP adapter](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html)  .

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ exposes a REST api to do various operations on it. Like publishing message to an exchange, consuming message from a queue, find list of queues etc.
So if your code is in js then you can nicely integrate your application to RabbitMQ by invoking the REST endpoints exposed by RabbitMQ.